# Create a wifi hotspot in a Desktop

Tags: wireless-networking, router, hotspot

I have a Windows XP desktop and I need to create a wifi hotspot there so that I can share the internet connection on my Desktop. I don't have any wifi devices on my Desktop. Now the problem is that I don't have a device to create a wifi hotspot. Do I need to buy a Wifi router for that? Or are there any other devices available? Could you please let me know?

Comment: What is your internet connection? Are you in a LAN or are you directly connected to a modem?

Comment: It is a LAN connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in a LAN and want to share the existing internet connection, the best and easiest option is to buy an [**Access Point**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_point).

An Access Point only has one plug, which is meant for the network cable. It will be connected to the LAN just like your computer.

You can then configure the Access Point in order to set up a wireless network that people can connect to. When people are connected to this Access Point, they will have access to the internet like every other computer in the LAN. Being connected to the Access Point therefore is the same as plugging in a network cable.

[image: network diagram]

***Note**: You can technically also buy a router, as it offers the same functionality – every router has a built-in Access Point. But it's unnecessary as you already have an internet connection and routers are meant for connecting a LAN and a WAN (e.g., the "Internet").*

Comment: What about the source computer? How does the Access Point connect to the Source Computer? I don't have a wifi there? Does it use USB to connect to Access Point?

Comment: The access point does not need to know about the "source computer". In fact, they don't need to know each other at all. Once you have configured the access point (AP) and connected it to your wired LAN, it sits in your network like every other computer.

Comment: But I need to connect to the source computer. If I have some HTTP server running on the source system, I should be able to access that from the Target systems also.

Comment: Yes, you can always connect to the source computer. When the AP and your computer are in the same LAN, you can *always* connect to the computer, even if you're in the wireless network.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't entirely clear but if you're asking:

My computer has an internet connection, but I want that connection to be available wirelessly to aerial devices.

You'll need a wireless router, or access point. They vary in performance and ranges so I can't be more specific.

Comment: Ya , I think I need a wireless router to share the connection with other devices. We have Bluetooth dongle to exchange data between PC and Bluetooth devices. I'm looking for a wifi equivalent of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have LAN connectivity,Then using **"Connectify"**  Software You Can **Sharing** Your Internet **without** Using Any Devices like,Router,Hub,Switch.